# Deleting objects of different types

Tags: c#, object

I have a project where I have to create a hierarchy of objects using a web api, akin to a database e.g. I need to create object types of database, which will contain tables, which in turn will contain columns. Each object is created by a call to the web service, which then returns its unique Id. I keep all this information by adding each object to a list in just case there's an error in the process.

```
List<object> dbObjects = new List<object>();
```

The problem comes when an exception occurs and I need to rollback. I need to go through the list and attempt to delete them one by one, which is where my query rears its ugly head. There are no interfaces or commonality apart from the object id.

What I'd kind of like to do is:

```
    foreach (object dbObject in dbObjects )
    {
        _webApi.DeleteObject <typeof(object)>(object.id);
    }
```

But you can't, or even:

```
foreach (object dbObject in dbObjects)
{
    switch (dbObject.GetType())
    {
        case typeof(Database):
            Database db = dbObject as Database 
            _webApi.DeleteObject <Database>(db.id);
            break;
        case typeof(Table):
            Table db = dbObject as Table;
            _webApi.DeleteObject<Table>(db.Id);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

but you can't. Any ideas on how to implement this kid of requirement gracefully would be much appreciated.

Stu.

Comment: A `List<object>` is *not a hierarchy*, it is - as the name implies - a flat list. Also, doing everything with `object` is totally ignoring everything that **strong typing** has to offer. Why not create a `List<Database>`, with each `Database` having a `List<DbTable>` and each `DbTable` having a `List<DbColumn>`?

Comment: It really is THAT simple, and clearly so am I!

Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple unrelated types in the same list is a bit of a code smell, I would advise refactoring your code so that wasn't the case, even simply keeping the objects in distinct lists for example. Having said that, you can do something like this:

```
foreach (var dbObject in dbObjects)
{
    switch (dbObject)
    {
        case Database db:
            _webApi.DeleteObject<Database>(db.id);
            break;

        case Table tbl:
            _webApi.DeleteObject<Table>(tbl.id);
            break;

        default:
            throw new Exception("Someone added a weird object to the collection...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, this would work but you and Peter are correct in your initial statements.

Answer (score -1):

you can use hashmap Hashtable data,it like,

```
Hashtable temp = new Hashtable();
temp.Add(object.id, object);
```

and delete data, you can use remove function, like:

```
temp.Remove(object.id);
```